# Find Table objects in the active sheet to remove auto filter

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, excel-tables, listobject

I need to find the one table (one worksheet will only have one Table) in the Active worksheet and find the first & last column in that table and remove the auto filter from those first and last columns.

Currently I am doing this:- The problem is I have to manually input the Field values as the name of the sheet will change as well as the name of the table

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
' Select middle cell
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Select
' Remove autofilter from first column in the table
With Range("$A$2")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=False
End With
' Remove autofilter from last column in the table
With Range("$Q$2")
    .AutoFilter Field:=17, VisibleDropDown:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Remove Filters From Columns of an Excel Table (`Workbook_SheetActivate`)

- Copy the code into the `ThisWorkbook` module.
- When activating (selecting) another worksheet, if it contains an Excel table, the filters in the first and last columns will be removed so will their dropdown arrows.
- To test it, filter a table by the first, by another, and by the last columns. After selecting another worksheet and then selecting the first worksheet, only the filter of the other column remains.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    On Error Resume Next
        Set tbl = Sh.ListObjects(1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
        With tbl.Range
            .Columns(1).AutoFilter 1, VisibleDropdown:=False
            .Columns(.Columns.Count).AutoFilter .Columns.Count, _
                VisibleDropdown:=False
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit: Excluding Worksheets**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    ' To exclude charts (kind of covered with 'On Error' statement).
    'If sh.Type <> xlWorksheet Then Exit Sub 
    
    Dim Exceptions As Variant: Exceptions = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

    ' To exclude the sheets in the list:    
    If IsError(Application.Match(Sh.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
    ' To restrict to the sheets in the list:
    'If IsNumeric(Application.Match(Sh.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
        
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        On Error Resume Next
            Set tbl = Sh.ListObjects(1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
            With tbl.Range
                .Columns(1).AutoFilter 1, VisibleDropdown:=False
                .Columns(.Columns.Count).AutoFilter .Columns.Count, _
                    VisibleDropdown:=False
            End With
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: works perfectly. Anyway to exclude some sheets?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
     
    With Me.ListObjects
        If .Count = 1 Then
            With .Item(1).Range
                .AutoFilter Field:=1
                .AutoFilter Field:=.Columns.Count
            End With
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @QHarr Shows filter arrows yes